# ng-repeat X for 5 times, then Y once and continue repeating X

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to set ng-repeat to repeat items X from an array 5 times, then add item Y, and continue repeating X.

The desired result would be:

```
<div>{{x.item}}</div>
<div>{{x.item}}</div>
<div>{{x.item}}</div>
<div>{{x.item}}</div>
<div>{{x.item}}</div>
<div>{{y.item}}</div>
<div>{{x.item}}</div>
<div>{{x.item}}</div>
```

...

I hope that explains it. Y item could also be a div whose contents do not come from said array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may doing something like:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="x in items">
    {{x.item}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-if="$index === 5">
    {{y.item}}
</div>
```

Comment: this is what the `%` operator is for;  `$index % 5 == 0` would give the same result.

Comment: I bet @PaulVO wants not each fifth, but just fifth iteration. `ng-if="$index === 5"`

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what I wanted. So with $index % 5 it would give me every fifth, whereas $index === 5 would give me just the fifth?

Comment: Yes. `$index % 5 == 0 && $index > 0` for every fifth.